# Ruby: Shorthand for associative hash/array from mysql2 result set

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, mysql2, associative

So, new to ruby and struggling on this:

images table - 2 columns, filename and md5
using the mysql2 extension

```
images = Hash.new
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM images").each do |row|
    images[row['filename']] = row['md5']
end
```

i'd like to just do this automatically, it seems pointless to loop through to make a hash - I think that I have missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
images = Hash[*Image.all.map{ |i| [i.filename, i.md5] }.flatten]
```

Comment: how do it put that in with the SQL query ?

Comment: You can try `images = Hash[*client.query("SELECT * FROM images").map{ |i| [i.filename, i.md5] }.flatten]`